# Read file continuously and update Python GTK application accordingly

Tags: python, events, gtk

I am working on a gesture recognition project. There is a C program that captures the gestures from video input and write them to the file. Now, I have an image viewer written in Python - GTK. It switches to the next or previous window according to gestures. This continuous file read and application update is defined as follows:

```
def ai(self):
        if self.mtime!=os.stat("input.txt").st_mtime:
            self.mtime=os.stat("input.txt").st_mtime
            inp=open("input.txt", "r");
            line=inp.read()
            if len(line)!=0:
                line=line[0:len(line)-1]
                for x in line.split(' '):
                    y=x.split('-')
                    if(y[1]=="R"):
                        self.next()
                        print "Move Right"
                    elif(y[1]=="L"):
                        self.prev()
                        print "Move Left"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "WakeUp"
        self.ai()
```

Now if I comment out the recursive call here, then application works after reading present file and updating images. Of course, then it doesn't update afterwards.

But if I uncomment the recursive call, then the console keeps on working but image-viewer application stops responding.

Is there any way to perform this function? Any event where i could bind this `ai()` function that could check for file updates every time that event is fired...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to my answer below: you should save the result of your `os.stat("input.txt").st_mtime` in a variable before the `if`, and then recycle the value in the assignment in the `if` clause itself. Function calls in python are expensive: if you are to insert `ai` in the main GTK loop this might be called hundreds of times per second...

Comment: yeah... it was the next thing i was going to do... :) thnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I would expect what you want to do is to **schedule a call to `ai()` in your main GTK loop**, so that your program checks if there is input on a regular base.

If this is what you want you have two choices: scheduling the call periodically or schedule the call for when the program is idle (it is not doing anything else).

Your code should look something like:

```
gobject.idle_add(callback, ...)  #execute callback when idle
gobject.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...)  #execute callback every interval millisecs
```

The documentation should be [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html) but presently there is a server error. Here are the relevant passages:

> The **`gobject.idle_add()`** function adds a function (specified by callback) to be called whenever there are no higher priority events pending to the default main loop. The function is given the default idle priority, gobject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE. Additional arguments to pass to callback can be specified after callback. The idle priority can be specified as a keyword-value pair with the keyword "priority". If callback returns FALSE it is automatically removed from the list of event sources and will not be called again.
>
> The **`gobject.timeout_add()`** function sets a function (specified by callback) to be called at regular intervals (specified by interval, with the default priority, gobject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT. Additional arguments to pass to callback can be specified after callback. The idle priority may be specified as a keyword-value pair with the keyword "priority".

A catch: you have your callbacks to return `True` if you want to keep them in the scheduler, failing to do so will make them execute only once.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have no experience whatsoever using pygtk.

I guess to make this work, you have to let the GTK event loop call your code (your recursive call makes it so that control never returns to the event loop).

You probably have two options:

- Either set up a timer event to call your method every nnn milliseconds ([tutorial](http://www.moeraki.com/pygtktutorial/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TimeoutsIOAndIdleFunctions.html#sec-Timeouts))
- Or use some sort of idle event to call your method whenever the GTK program is otherwise idle ([tutorial](http://www.moeraki.com/pygtktutorial/pygtk2tutorial/sec-IdleFunctions.html))

Comment: In the code above, i am trying the timer method only. It hangs up the  application to that function call only. GTK application never gets the control back. And I tried looking and testing every event that i could find suitable for this. But it's of no use. Do you know any event that gets executed every second or so..?

Comment: although your answer is also correct, but mac told me the exact thing to do. so upvote for you and right answer for him. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `gtk`, you could use `gio` module to do the monitoring for you, instead of your own custom solution to periodically poll the file state:

```
monitor = gio.File(filename).monitor()
monitor.connect('changed', file_changed_cb)
```

Note that you can connect the `changed` signal to your callback to perform any update that you need.